# Combine ipe and beamer presentation (font identification)

Tags: beamer, fonts

I am trying to  transition from an  existing ipe presentation to beamer by combining slides from both into the same presentation.  To do this I need to match the existing slides in beamer, a job that shouldn't be too hard I thought. However, can anyone tell me how to reproduce the [following](http://www.cs.bris.ac.uk/~clifford/test.pdf) please.

My first problem is the font.  Using acroread or pdffonts to determine the fonts used I get a long list that I can't interpret. whatthefont.com gives a few options and the closest is http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/processtype/seravek/extra-light/ which I find hard to believe.

Comment: The fonts are the standard Computer Modern Sans. There are other CM fonts, probably because the `test.pdf` has been extracted from a bigger one.

Comment: Thanks, I should have noticed that. Just need to get it exactly the same in Beamer now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fonts are easy, actually only three of them are used in the page that was extracted from a larger file via `pdftk`:

- The header was set in CMSS12.
- For the text CMSS10 is used.
- The item bullets come from CMSY10.

The prefixes, seen in the output of `pdffonts` are typically added for fonts that are not embedded as full fonts, but using a subset of the needed characters.

An example file that shows the font usages.
Edit: Paper layout added and font sizes fixed.
The header font is scaled by a factor of 2.8 and the text font by a factor of 2.4.
The example therefore uses `\mag=2400` and `\Large` instead of `\large` for the header font to get 2.8/2.4 scaling.

```
\mag=2400
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  paperwidth=800truebp,
  paperheight=600truebp,
  lmargin=32truebp,
  rmargin=16truebp,
  vmargin=24truebp,
]{geometry}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{.2,.2,.6}
\pagestyle{empty}
\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\setlength{\leftmargini}{1.5em}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\textcolor{myblue}{\Large Data Structure Lower Bounds}
\end{center}
\vspace{-10truebp}

\noindent
Predecessor (static)
\begin{compactitem}
\item Ajtai Combinatorica '88
\item Miltersen STOC' 94
\item Miltersen, Nisan, Safra, Wigdersen STOC '95
\item Beame, Fich STOC '99
\item Sen ICALP '01
\end{compactitem}

\bigskip

\noindent
Dynamic problems (partial sums, union find)
\begin{compactitem}
\item Fredman, Saks STOC '89
\item Ben-Amram, Galil FOCS '91
\item Miltersen, Subramanian, Vitter, Tamassia TCS '94
\item Husfeldt, Rauhe, Skyum SWAT '96 (planar connectivity)
\item Fredman, Henzinger Algorithmica '98 (non-determinism)
\item Alstrup, Husfeldt, Rauhe FOCS '98 (marked ancestor)
\item Alstrup, Husfeldt, Rauhe SODA '01 (2D NN)
\item Alstrup, Ben-Amram, Rauhe STOC '99 (union-find)
\end{compactitem}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]